# Lowest number challenge scheme

Tags: protocol-design, reference-request, homomorphic-encryption

Suppose Alice knows a secret number $a$, and Bob knows a secret number $b$.

Is there a simple way for Alice and Bob to know who has the lowest number, without Alice & Bob exchanging their numbers ?

Comment: This is Yao's Millionaires' Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao's_Millionaires'_Problem

Comment: @Seth : $\;\;\;$ It's _at least approximately_ that problem. $\:$ If ties are supposed to be broken at random, $\hspace{.41 in}$ then this question's problem may be more difficult. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer In that case a tie could be broken with Blum's "coin-flipping by telephone".

Comment: @fkraiem remember though, you would have to always run the coin-flip (whether there was a tie or not), otherwise you leak whether or not there was a tie. My point is, things can get complicated.

Comment: @fkraiem : $\;\;\;$ How would that work? $\:$ Any use of that paper that I can think of would leak $\hspace{.83 in}$ which side a tie would have been broken in favor of. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @owlstead : $\:$ "If you always run both of them," you'd be revealing whether or not $\:a=b\;$. $\hspace{.98 in}$

Comment: An adversary can just give the output of the Socialist Millionaire protocol. $\;$

Comment: Ah, OK. I guess I have to read more into it, my apologies.